# Adding complex data structure in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a set of data that I'd like to look like this:

```
{
   "city" : "new york",
   "state" : "missouri",
   "data" : {
       2012 : {
          volume : {
              cars : 12,
              trucks : 13,
              ...
          },
          price : {
              cars : 1234,
              trucks : 1343,
              ...
          }
       },                 
       2004 : { another year like 2012 },
       ...
    }
}
```

And here is my mongoose schema object:

```
var carMakerObject = mongoose.Schema({
    city : "string",
    state : "string",
    loc: { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere'},
    data: {
       2012 : {
         volume :  {type: Number, trim: true},
         price :  {type: Number, trim: true},
       }
       ...
    })
```

I guess my question is, how can I set up a complex data object that is an object with objects inside the object? I've played around with different syntaxes, but I'm missing something. I'm going to be adding even more data to this schema, and I'd like to keep it flexible and easily expandable.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alex, this is partly a MongoDB modeling question and partly a Mongoose implementation question. In order to receive a good answer you would need to describe what you need the model for. Are there more read or write requests? How will the data grow? How much is it anyway? etc... I suggest that you have a look at the [MongoDB data modelling best practices](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) first and then further specify your question...

Comment: Thanks, mbernath. I'm going to try to reformulate my question more specifically and then try again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728189/mongoose-mongo-structure-for-a-data-map I ended up re-writing the question completely to make the problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
var carMaker = {
   "city" : "new york",
   "state" : "missouri",
   "data" : {
       2012 : {
          volume : {
              cars : 12,
              trucks : 13,
              ...
          },
          price : {
              cars : 1234,
              trucks : 1343,
              ...
          }
       },                 
       2004 : { another year like 2012 },
       ...
    }
}

carMakerModel.create(carMaker);
```

`carMakerModel` is the model name.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26312696)